# assign stored procedure result to list using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, stored-procedures, label

I'm using Entity Framework and what i want is to show stored procedure result into different labels like attribute News = lblnews.text and date = lblDate.text
as far as i know i've to populate the result into list from stored procedure this is what i'm trying to do .. or if there is any other way please let me know

```
    dbContext = new OnlineDvdShopDBEntities();
    List<string> News = new List<string>();
    news = dbContext.spGetLatestNews();
```

i've search  a lot on google but have no idea how to do.. my database is sending me a row of columns News Description and News Date that i want to store in particular labels..

Comment: lblnews.text = news.FirstOrDefault().NewsDescription;

Comment: but its giving me compile time error while assigning stored procedure result into news.. the error is cannot implicity convert type method to list

Comment: var temp = dbContext.spGetLatestNews(); lblnews.text = temp.FirstOrDefault().NewsDescription; –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning results of stored procedure to list of strings, but result of that procedure is not list of strings. You can use `var` keyword to declare variable. The actual type will be inferred automatically:

```
var temp = dbContext.spGetLatestNews(); 
var firstNew = temp.FirstOrDefault();

if(firstNew != null)
{
    lblnews.Text = firstNew.NewDescription;
    ...
}
```